# getting undefined behavior in counting characters of text file program?

Tags: c, io, scanf, fopen

I wrote a c program meant to count the characters in a certain file.

```
int main(void) {
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("txt.txt", "r");
    char text;
    int count;
    while (fscanf(fp, "%c", &text) != EOF) {
        count++;
    }
    printf("%d", count);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to add a char array into it but for some reason it changes the value of my int type (count).
for example, if I run this program I get an output of 3549. Now, lets say I declare "`char potato[5000]`" alongside my other char type. For some reason I get a completely different output of 159062601. Why is this and how do I prevent that?

Comment: Try `int count = 0;`

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: What you're describing is *undefined behaviour* and it's caused by a number of things, but most commonly it's *using uninitialized variables* like `count` here. That does not default to 0. It defaults to *whatever*, or in other words the random garbage you're seeing.

Comment: just initialize count as 0, you should be good to go

Comment: Enable all warnings and debug info in your compiler. With [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compile `yourcode.c` with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g yourcode.c -o yourprog`. Learn to use a debugger such as [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)

Comment: It's worth nothing that this mystery could have been solved in seconds by stepping through in a debugger where it would be obvious that `count` has a garbage value before the first iteration. This is why learning to use a debugger is an essential skill when working with C code.

Comment: Read [*What every C programmer should know about undefined behavior*](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html)

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  Amongst other things, it is missing the statement: `#include <stdiio.h>`

Comment: regarding: `fp = fopen("txt.txt", "r");`  ALWAYS follow a call to `fopen()` with `if( ! fp ) { perror( "fopen failed" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`  where `exit()` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are exposed via: `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: This seems related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong?r=SearchResults&s=2|248.5730

Comment: On Linux, consider using [stat(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) since the file size is part of its metadata.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have  several problems in your code. i will list them below:

1. In `c` programming we declare variables in the scope begin. and initialize them if we need so. you have a mixture of declerations and code.
2. `count` variable non initialized!! you have entered the while loop with garbage value in count. UB (Undefined behavior) - in each run you will get different values.
3. you didnt check the return value of `fopen` !! you must check if the operating system succed in opening the file you have requested to manipulate.
4. regarding asking a question in stackoverflow, your code is not complete and you didnt post all of it.

Now lets try to learn new topics regarding working with IO streams.

`return value of function fscanf`

> The value `EOF` is returned if the end of input is reached before
> either the first successful conversion or a matching `failure occurs`.
> `EOF` is also returned if a `read error` occurs, in which case the
> error indicator for the stream (`see ferror(3)`) is set, and `errno`
> is set indicate the error.

This is how check if errors ocured while working with the file we are reading:

`int ferror(FILE *stream);`

> The function ferror() tests the error indicator for the stream pointed
> to by stream, returning nonzero if it is set. The error indicator can
> only be reset by the clearerr() function.

And in this function bellow we get a human readble error, not just an errnor number!

**explain_ferror**

`const char *explain_ferror(FILE *fp);`

> The explain_ferror function is used to obtain an explanation of an
> error returned by the ferror(3) system call. The least the message
> will contain is the value of strerror(errno), but usually it will do
> much better, and indicate the underlying cause in more detail.
>
> The errno global variable will be used to obtain the error value to be
> decoded.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libexplain/ferror.h>   /* for the non standard const char* explain_ferror(FILE* fp); */

int main(void) 
{
    FILE *fp;
    char text;
    int count = 0;
    
    fp = fopen("txt.txt", "r");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        perror("fopen failed");  /*write to standard error*/ 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (fscanf(fp, "%c", &text) != EOF) 
    {
        ++count;
    }
    
    if (ferror(fp))  /* nonzero return if error occured */
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", explain_ferror(fp));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }  
    
    printf("%d", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Since the `const char *explain_ferror(FILE *fp);` is not GNU standard function, i am posting a GNU standard functions in the code snippet below:

`char *strerror(int errnum);`

`strerror` is standard library c function which returns a pointer to a string that describes the error code passed in the argument `errnum`. Be aware that this function is not `Thread safe`. for thread safe function use The `strerror_r()`.

**Return Value**

The strerror(), function return the appropriate error description string, or an "Unknown error nnn" message if the error number is unknown.

Since `POSIX.1-2001` and `POSIX.1-2008` requires that a successful call to strerror() shall leave `errno` unchanged, and note that, since no function return value is reserved to indicate an error, if we wishe to check for errors we should initialize errno to zero before the call (by calling `void clearerr(FILE *stream);`, and then check errno after the call.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>  

...

clearerr(fp);  /* clear previous seted errno */

while (fscanf(fp, "%c", &text) != EOF) 
{
    ++count;
}
    
if (ferror(fp))  /* nonzero return if error occured */
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}  

...
```

Finally:
man pages (or man7) or typing `man <enter_string_here>` in terminal on linux shall clear all the q.marks.
for further reading go to:

[explain_ferror](https://linux.die.net/man/3/explain_ferror)

[ferror](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ferror)

[fscanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fscanf)

Comment: Remember, ALL code needs to be indented at least 4 spaces, other wise it  will be treated as text rather than code.  failed to initialize `count`  failed to add the trailing `'\n' to the format string of the call to `printf()`  Other things can cause `fscanf()` to fail besides EOF, should be checking the count of successful 'input format conversion' specifiers

Comment: @user3629249- now i have compeleted my answer. i am slowly man! :-). thanks for the comment.

Comment: "The error indicator can only be reset by the clearerr() function." --> `rewind()`, `freopen()` also clear it.

Comment: "if a read error occurs ...errno is set indicate the error." - that is not specified by C nor the standard C lib.  `explain_ferror()` is also not specified there.

Comment: `if (ferror(fp) < 0)` better as `if (ferror(fp))` since the return value is not specified to be negative but "The ferror function returns nonzero if and only if the error indicator is set for stream."

Comment: you are right its not standard. include shall be made to use it. its taken from an official website die.net and its in the lib/header <libexplain/ferror.h>.

Comment: @Olivier-John Nzia - if my answer was useful i would be glad if you accept it by pushing the (grey " V " nearby the answer begin). thanks

Answer (score 4):

The following proposed code:

1. initializes variables before using them (your compiler should have told you about this problem.
2. properly checks and handles I/O errors for `fopen()` and for `fscanf()`
3. properly closes the open file before exiting.  I.E. it cleans up after itself
4. properly terminates printed text, so it is immediately passed to the terminal

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void) 
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("txt.txt", "r");
    if( ! fp )
    {
        perror( "fopen failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    
    char text;
    int count = 0;

    while ( fscanf( fp, "%c", &text ) == 1 ) 
    {
        count++;
    }

    fclose( fp );

    printf( "%d\n", count );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Always prefer the compare to desired result as in `fscanf( fp, "%c", &text ) == 1` as this answer does versus the compare to one undesired result as with OP's `fscanf(fp, "%c", &text) != EOF`.